# Sections which generate globally, generate global sections.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, projective-space

I am not sure so I'll ask just in case. Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal F$ a sheaf of modules on $X$ which is globally generated by $\{s_i\}$. Do these sections also generate $\Gamma(X,\mathcal F)$ as a module ?

Is it true if we suppose that there are finitely many generators, or more ?

In fact I tried to show that a morphism $\phi\colon\mathbb P^n_K\to \mathbb P^m_K$ with $n>m$ is constant. I argued by contradiction using that $\phi^*(x_1),\dots,\phi^*(x_m)$ were generators of $\phi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^m_K}(1)$ (in fact they are global generators by Hartshorne II.7.1) and said that $\Gamma(\mathbb P^n_K,\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_K}(d))$ had a too big dimension for $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n_K}(d)$ to be isomorphic to $\phi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^m_K}(1)$. But this argument might not work since it relies on saying that the dimension of $\Gamma(\mathbb P^n_K,\phi^*\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^m_K}(1))$ is at most $m$.

Comment: Let $V=\oplus_i {\cal O}_X$ and let $V\to M$ be the corresponding surjection (given by the $s_i$), where $M$ is your square (I don't know how to Tex a square). Let $K$ be the kernel of $V\to M$. Then the answer to your question is yes iff the induced map $H^1(X,K)\to H^1(X,V)$ is injective. This follows from the existence of the long exact sequence of cohomology groups associated with a short exact sequence.

Comment: In the answer below, $K={\cal O}(-2)$ and so $H^1(X,K)$ is one-dimensional. On the other hand, $H^1(X,V)=0$. So the induced map $H^1(X,K)\to H^1(X,V)$ is not injective.

Comment: For the question about the morphism between projective spaces, consider that $\phi$ must be given by some ${\cal O}(k)$, with $k\geq 0$ (because the Picard group of projective space is generated by ${\cal O}(1)$). Suppose first that $k>0$. Let $F$ be a fibre of $\phi$. Then ${\cal O}(k)|_F$ is trivial and ample, so $F$ must be finite (otherwise the trivial bundle is ample on a irreducible component of dimension $>0$ of $F$, which is impossible). Hence $\phi$ is finite. But this contradicts $n>m$. So $k=0$ and so $\phi$ is constant.

Comment: @DamianRössler And is it wrong to say that since the $x_i$ generate the global sections (not only globally this time) on $\mathbb P^m$, then their pullbacks $\phi^*(x_i)$ generate $\Gamma(X,\phi^*\mathcal O(1))$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take, for example, the sheaf $\mathcal O(2)$ on projective line with coordinates $(x_0:x_1)$. It is globally generated by sections $x_0^ 2$ and $x_1^2$, but they do not generate the space of global sections.

Comment: But we can still form a basis of sections which globally generate our sheaf if the dimension of globals actions is finite right ?

Comment: @raisinsec: For example, there may be no non-zero global sections.

Comment: I agree but in the finite dimensional case where we know there are nonzero global sections ?

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by finite-dimensional case. For example, the sheaf $\mathcal O(-1)$ on projective space has no nonzero global sections.

Comment: I mean suppose $\Gamma(X,\mathcal L)\neq 0$ and is finite dimensional with sections which generate globally. This is the case of the question basically. Then we can just complete it (or extract from it) a basis, which will give a basis of sections which generate globally $\mathcal L$. It is nothing deep, just that in this case we can take sections which generate globally to be a basis of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal L)$.

Comment: Yes, of course, but this does not help to solve your question on maps of projective spaces. It is solved by noting that such a map should be finite, which is proven directly e.g. in Shafarevich's Basic Algebraic Geometry I, paragraph on finite maps.